# DialogFragment with a custom title

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I need to place a custom title to my `DialogFragment`.

```
getDialog().setTitle("My Title");
```

is not enough for me because I want to change the title text and background colors.

As you can see from the image below, with `getDialog().setTitle("My Title");` I've no customization (as far as I know), ie, the text color is black and the background is white.

My objective is to have `My Title` customized as seen by `Custom Title`. I've been looking around the API and I couldn't find any method to load a view into the title section.

Anyone knows how can I customize or set/inject a view into the `FragmentDialog`?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216615/customizing-android-dialogfragment?rq=1).  Basically, use the Dialog Builder to create a new Dialog and set its view to a layout you defined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create a custom dialog by overiding onCreateDialog like so:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_change_password, null);

    /* Anything that needs to be done to the view, ie. 
    on click listeners, postivie/negative buttons,
    values being changed etc */

    builder.setView(dialogView);
    return builder.create();
}
```

and the dialog_change_password.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white_grey">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/change_password"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/dialogHeading" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        style="@style/dialogSection">

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/PasswordChangeRow">

            <TextView
                style="@style/PasswordChangeLabel"
                android:text="@string/new_password"/>

            <EditText
                style="@style/PasswordChangeField"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            style="@style/PasswordChangeRow">

            <TextView
                style="@style/PasswordChangeLabel"
                android:text="@string/confirm_password"/>

            <EditText
                style="@style/PasswordChangeField"
                android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/password_conditions_message"
        style="@style/dialogMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously that xml is a bit more complex that what is needed but is just an example of what can be done, it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setCustomTitle` method, where you can inflate your own fully customized layout

Example

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

public class PromoDetailDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View titleView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_title, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) titleView.findViewById(R.id.my_title_textView);
        tv.setText("title");

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setCustomTitle(titleView)
                .setMessage("message")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .create();

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

This way is cleaner and much more powerful